# Finding the missing number in a sequence of factorials

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, factorial

On one of our tests, the extra credit was to find which number you would take out from the set $\{1!,2!,3!,...(N-1)!,N!\}$ such that the product of the set is a perfect square. My answer was as follows:

Assume $N$ is even. First note that  $(n!)=(n-1)!\cdot n$.

Apply this to the odd numbers to get the product:
$$(2!)(2!)\cdot 3 \cdot(4!)(4!)\cdot 5\cdots ((N-2)!)((N-2)!)\cdot (N-1)\cdot N!$$

Let $ 2!4!6!...(N-2)!=E$. Then our equation is equal to: 
$$E^23\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdots (N-1)\cdot (N!)$$

Expand $N!$:

$$E^2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdots (N-1)\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdots N$$

Group the odd terms together:

$$E^2\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot  5\cdot 7 \cdot 7\cdots (N-1)\cdot 2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots N$$

Let $O=1\cdot3\cdot5...\cdot (N-1)$:

$$E^2O^2 2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots N = E^2O^2\cdot (2\cdot 2)\cdot (2\cdot 3)\cdot (2\cdot 4)\cdots (2\cdot (N/2))$$

Group together the $2$'s:

$$E^2O^22^{(N/2)}1\cdot2\cdot3...(N/2)=E^2O^22^{(N/2)}\cdot(N/2)!$$

So, if $N/2$ is even, it can be expressed as $2m$ for some $m$. So we have:

$$E^2O^22^{2m}(N/2)!=(EO2^m)^2(N/2)!$$
Therefore, if $N$ is even, the number missing is $(N/2)!$ if $N/2$ is even. For example, for $N=4$, $2!$ is missing, $N=6$ is impossible ($3$ is odd), and for $N=100$, $50!$ is missing.

I got partial credit - but my teacher said I missed a case, and that I should leave a sticky note on her desk with a number on it to show that I've fixed the proof.

I think the flaw might be in assuming $N$ is even, but I'm not sure how to deal with the case of $N$ odd.

And, I've found that my solution gives $4!$ for $N=8$, but $3!$ is also a solution. 
Past that, how can one number show that I've fixed the proof?

Comment: Yes, don't you have to consider the case $N$ is odd?

Comment: @JimmyR. Yes! But I don't know how to go about that, nor how I would express the solution in one number.

Comment: Look at $N = 9$.

Comment: It is true that $\dfrac{1!2!3!4!5!6!7!8!}{4!}$ is a square.  But so too is $\dfrac{1!2!3!4!5!6!7!8!}{3!}$.  And something similar when $N=8k^2$ for other $k$

Answer (score 1):

According to the paper ["Square products of punctured sequences
of factorials"](https://www.austms.org.au/Publ/Gazette/2009/Nov09/TechPaperMabry.pdf) by Rick Mabry and Laura McCormick. The  given problem for $N\geq 2$ has at least a solution if ad only if $N$ is even and has one of the following forms:

1) $4k$ or $4k^2-2$ for any positive integer $k$ (take away $(2k)!$ and $(2k^2)!$ respectively);

2) $2k^2$ or $2k^2-4$ for any positive odd integer $k\geq 3$ such that $2(k^2-1)$ is a perfect square (take away $(k^2-2)!$ and $(k^2)!$ respectively).